# Error 5A - Internal CPU Error

Tags: cpu, motherboard

So I built myself a pc for the first time.  The machine has been running properly, and without issue, since March of this year.  Today after an hour or so of gaming the machine shutdown without warning.  Any attempts to reboot have been unsuccessful.  I have managed to get it to post, twice, but it doesn't get as far as the OS before it shuts off again.

I pulled the second video card so I could see the error code LED and it appears to be showing 5A which matches to "Internal CPU Error".  Am I looking at a failed CPU or is this a symptom of another issue?  Any feedback you can provide is most appreciated.

Here's my parts list:

CPU: Intel Core i7-4930K 3.4GHz 6-Core

CPU Cooler: Corsair H105 73.0 CFM Liquid

Motherboard: Asus X79 Deluxe ATX LGA2011

Ram: G.Skill Ripjaws X Series 32GB (4 x 8GB) DDR3-1600

Video card (x2): EVGA GeForce GTX 770 2GB

Power supply: Corsair 1000W ATX12V / EPS12V

Comment: http://rog.asus.com/forum/showthread.php?24573-Help-5A-quot-Internal-CPU-Error-quot

Comment: The error code seems pretty clear.  Your CPU has failed.

Comment: Thanks ali786, I read that one last night as well.  Looking for a second opinion, third opinion to confirm what it appears to be.  Thanks Ramhound for your input as well.

Comment: In fact the CPU had failed.  Contacted Intel, they sent a new one. Bingo bango, all sorted.